# Cronjob to cat all text files in a directory to one text file

Tags: cron

I want to setup a cronjob where I cat all text files in a directory into one text file titled `all_results.txt`.

The first line of my crontab is running the script that gathers and outputs probably 80-90 text files (which works fine).

The second line of my crontab that I have scheduled is like so:

```
0 18 * * * cat /home/ec2-user/subfinder_results_domains/*.txt > all_results.txt
```

For whatever reason it doesn't seem to run the second line of the cronjob.

Comment: Please also show us the first job in the crontab.  When you say it does not run the job, does it mean that you get an empty `all_results.txt` file or that you don't get that file at all (not even in your home directory)? Note that if you have one job that _depends_ on an earlier job, it is safer to combine these into a script that you schedule as a single job. That way, you can be sure that the first job finishes before the second one runs.

Answer (score 0):

The target file does not have an absolute path to it. So the cron puts the file down into its (cron's) current directory, whatever that directory is.

So the solution is obvious:

```
 18 * * * cat /home/ec2-user/subfinder_results_domains/*.txt > /var/log/all_results.txt
```

You can even dump the file into your own home:

```
 18 * * * cat /home/ec2-user/subfinder_results_domains/*.txt > /home/ec2-user/all_results.txt
```